# Are 2 independent PDAs equivalent to a turing machine?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, pushdown-automata

I was thinking about the language $a^nb^nc^n$, which is obviously not context free, but if we run it through 2 automata at the same time (the first for $a$ and $b$ and the second for $b$ and $c$ and they both accept, the construction would basically accept the language)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, such a construct can recognise at most the intersection of two context-free languages. To see where it's lacking, consider $L = \{\textsf{a}^n~|~n\in\mathbb{N}~\text{is composite}\}$. I conjecture that to express $L$ as the intersection of CFLs requires infinitely many CFLs.

The paper *An infinite hierarchy of intersections of context-free languages* by Liu and Weiner (Math. Systems Theory 7, 185–192 (1973). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01762237) presents languages that can be written as intersection by $k$ context-free languages but not by intersecting $k-1$-languages. For $k=3$ the language is $\{\; a^k b^\ell c^m a^k b^\ell c^m \mid k,\ell,m \in \mathbb{N}\}$.
Thus, that language is the intersection of three cf-languages, but not the intersection of two cf-languages.
For other $k$ the same pattern is repeated. The quote that paper "The proof is quite complicated".

The language
$\{\textsf{a}^n\textsf{b}^n\textsf{c}^n\textsf{d}^n\textsf{e}^n~|~n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ seems as complicated but is in fact the intersection of two cf-languages: $\{ \textsf{a}^m\textsf{b}^m\textsf{c}^n\textsf{d}^n\textsf{e}^p \mid m,n,p\in \mathbb N \} \cap\{ \textsf{a}^m\textsf{b}^n\textsf{c}^n\textsf{d}^p\textsf{e}^p \mid m,n,p\in \mathbb N \}   $.

Comment: @HendrikJan You're right! I'll edit but will keep my blunder so your valuable comment still makes sense.

Comment: I'm not very proud of my new example. Is there a simpler one?

Comment: I have added an example directly into your answer so you don't have to copy it. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @HendrikJan not at all. Thanks for finding the Liu/Weiner paper!

Answer (score 6):

What you actually ask is: can language of every grammar be represented as an intersection of two context-free languages?

The answer is **no**.
To prove that, we can observe that, while the class of context-free languages is not closed under intersection, the class of context-sensitive languages is.
This means that intersection of two CFLs is always a CSL (since every CFL is also a CSL).
If you could represent language of every grammar as an intersection of two (or, in general, any $k\in\mathbb{N}$) CFLs, it would mean that every grammar has context-sensitive language, which we know is not true.

Answer (score 3):

The language $\{a^nb^nc^n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ belongs to a strict subset of context-sensitive languages that can be expressed in terms of an intersection of two context-free languages.

Having two PDAs cannot recognize a language like $\{a^nb^nc^nd^ne^n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Two PDAs can match that though, one can check both on if the `a`s and `b`s are equal, then also check if the `c` and `d`s are equal. Then the other can check if the other side by side pairs are equal.